# Enum multiple cases with the same value in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

In C you could make your enums have this:

```
typedef enum _Bar {
    A = 0,
    B = 0,
    C = 1
} Bar;
```

In Swift I want to make the equivalent. However, the compiler complains that it isn't unique. How do I tell it that I want two cases to have the same value?

```
enum Bar : Int {
    case A = 0
    case B = 0 // Does not work
    case C = 1
}
```

I've tried

```
case A | B = 0
```

and

```
case A, B = 0
```

But it doesn't seem to work as I want it to.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Swift doesn't support duplicated values (or "aliases" semantically). If you don't mind, you can mimic it by using something like this:

```
enum Foo: Int {
    case Bar = 0

    static var Baz:Foo {
        get {
            return    Bar
        }
    }
    static var Jar:Foo {
        get {
            return    Foo(rawValue: 0)!
        }
    }
}
```

With recent version of Swift, this can be shortened like this:

```
enum Foo: Int {
    case bar = 0

    static var baz:Foo { .bar }
    static var jar:Foo { Foo(rawValue: 0)! }
}
```

Note that Swift has changed their naming convention of enum variants from [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) to [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

Comment: Or, since properties are implied to have getter code if neither `get` nor `set` is specified, you can shorten these up to `static var Baz:Foo { return Bar }` and `static var Jar:Foo { return Foo(rawValue: 0)! }`.

Comment: Or, it seem in Swift 3, stored class properties will work so just `static let Baz = Foo.Bar` and `static let Jar = Foo(rawValue: 0)!`.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson I think using `let` will occupy extra memory to store copy and create a different identity for the storage. Therefore slightly different in theory. In reality, I am not sure how compiler would work with it.

Comment: Slightly more memory while slightly less processing time.  I usually err on the side of “memory is cheap” when programming in any language— recomputing things on-demand tend to have a higher chance of running away performance-wise than just properly storing pre-computed values.  I also find it's easier to track down and fix bloated memory usage than algorithmic performance issues— the former can be snapshotted and inspected easily with modern tools, while the latter is more often than not nuanced and snapshot-time sensitive— it may not occur at all for some users, but plague others.

Comment: TL;DR: For something as small and trivial as this, it honestly doesn't matter.  But for the sake of choosing a programming style and sticking with it top-to-bottom, I like to compute things once and then hold onto them in memory for as long as they might be needed, or for simple data like this, for the duration of the program.  _(Of course, when programming for GPUs, I completely flip that approach and prefer algorithms.)_

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how much optimization Swift and LLVM do, but coming from a C++ & Obj-C background, I learned that there are lots of ways to make things constant which'll hint to the compiler that it doesn't actually need to store the value in memory— it can just inline/“hard-code” the value into the assembly instructions.  That seems less likely to happen when you're explicitly calling a `Foo(rawValue:)` constructor.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Well, the constructor in this case is can be verified as no-op very easily and likely to be eliminated by optimizer. I am pretty sure that your code and my code would produce same machine code. And I'm not sure whether Swift actually guarantees copying and fixed static storage (and address to it) for `let` values. In theory, let values can become a dynamically resolved function.

Comment: @eonil Swift supports duplicate raw values for enum cases: [It is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62884952/13426627). Although the engineers need to fix this, as it causes a lot of havoc.

Comment: @0-1 As far as I remember it was impossible a few years ago and now it seems something's been changed. Is this an intentional design?

Comment: @eonil I'm not sure if it's intentional. I'll do some research on it. I'm pretty sure the Documentation still says it's not ok:“Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or floating-point number types. Each raw value must be unique within its enumeration declaration.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.2).” Apple Books. https://books.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-5-2/id881256329

Comment: @eonil I reported it as a bug [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13212) but it has been closed. Apparently it is now a feature. (Although a secret, and one that I would not recommend using, but a feature nonetheless)

Comment: @0-1 Your code snippet Is *how to convert values into enum cases*, not really *defining multiple enum cases with duplicated underlying value*. Very far away from what OP asked.

Answer (score 14):

Here is another way of getting around it:

```
enum Animal {

  case dog
  case cat
  case mouse
  case zebra

  var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .dog:
      return "dog"

    case .cat:
      return "dog"

    case .mouse:
      return "dog"

    case .zebra:
      return "zebra"

    default:
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift doesn't allow elements of an `enum`to share values. From the documentation on enums under the "Raw Values" heading (emphasis mine):

> Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or floating-point number types. **Each raw value must be unique within its enumeration declaration.**

Comment: You can always create constant class members to construct aliased values if that's what you want-they can be used in constructors and assignments but not in switch statements.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you can. The following is taken from Apple.

> “Unlike C and Objective-C, Swift enumeration members are not assigned a default integer value when they are created. In the CompassPoints example above, North, South, East and West do not implicitly equal 0, 1, 2 and 3. Instead, the different enumeration members are fully-fledged values in their own right, with an explicitly-defined type of CompassPoint.”

Excerpt from: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11

Since the enumeration members do not implicitly equal 0, 1, etc., the compiler looks at each as a unique value.  When you try and duplicate it the compiler complains because it has already been created.

Comment: Yes I want to use enums to represent index paths.  Different sections will have an enum and the row names would be associated with the row index.  Row index can be the same value but have different sections.

Comment: It sort of sounds like you want a struct then, not an enum.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem about multiple case with the same value. After googling this problem, I prefer the following solution with `computed properties` of `enum`, [which come from this post](https://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples/).

---

[image: Swift enum properties]

Answer (score 1):

You could easily override the `==` operator to return `true` every time, except that would be cheating. Let's do this the real way!

---

I disagree with the accepted answer: Swift **does** allow raw values to be equivalent, but it **does not** allow you to write interpretively identical literals. This may cause people to think that what you are asking is impossible. But, your question is answerable, and we will have to work around Swift's lexical grammar a little bit.

> i.e. 1.0 and 1.000 are interpretively identical Double literals, since the extra zeroes collapse.

The simplest proof of this is to take advantage over floating point type underflow/overflow. The literals themselves are not identical, but the values themselves are the same.

```swift
enum ExhibitA: Double {
    case a = 0.0
    case b = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
}
print(ExhibitA.a == ExhibitA.b) // true
print(ExhibitA.a.rawValue) // 0.0
print(ExhibitA.b.rawValue) // 0.0
```

So I technically answered your question, but this has no practical value. Let's try and make it work for all numbers, as well as include more types.

---

If you let your enum cases be JSON decodable String raw values, and apply the `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` protocol to convert them into their specified type, you can do just that.

```swift
import Foundation

struct EnumWrapper<T: Codable & Equatable>: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Equatable {
    var value: T
    init(_ t: T) { value = t }
    init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        try! self.init(JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: Data(value.utf8)))
    }
}


enum Foo: EnumWrapper<Int> {
    case a = "1"
    case b = "1 "
}
print(Foo.a == Foo.b) // true
print(Foo.a.rawValue.value) // 1
print(Foo.b.rawValue.value) // 1
```

Awesome! Now you can use as a raw value anything that conforms to `Decodable`.
i.e. a 4D Array of Booleans:

```swift
enum Example: EnumWrapper<[[[[Bool]]]]> {
    case woah = "[[[[true, false, true], [false], []], []]]"
}
print(Example.woah.rawValue.value) // [[[[true, false, true], [false], []], []]]
```

---

This pattern is dangerous when applied to Sets or Dictionaries. Half the time you run the code below, you will receive a run-time error saying the dictionary has duplicate keys.

```swift
let foo : [Foo : Bool] = [
    .a : true,
    .b : false
]
```

Comment: You kept demonstrating possibilities here by doing something you aren’t supposed to do: extending types you didn’t define to conform to protocols you didn't define. It’s okay to conform others’ types to your protocols and to conform your types to others’ protocols, but it’s not okay to conform others’ types to others’ protocols.

Comment: @ChristopherH. I've updated my answer in light of your comment. I believe what is now demonstrated above is a safer pattern, what do you think? Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I found this by sheer coincidence and was surprised there's no Swift-y dark magic in any of the answers (which are still good, of course). Personally I don't like the `static` properties as much because they introduce overhead elsewhere, e.g. in the pattern matching.

I think the "cleanest" solution would be to rely on `RawRepresentable` and define that yourself. Then you can counter the main reason why Swift doesn't support this out of the box: the `init?(rawValue:)` method. By just specifying String as the adopted raw value (i.e. `enum MyEnum: String { ... }`) the compiler can't generate the logic for that on its own. It would need to know which case to skip, as there are not "enough" potential raw values defined (since one or more are doubled). Adopting the protocol yourself allows you to simply chose one case as the "default" for a given raw value string and basically prevent the other one from constructed with a raw value (regular construction still works, of course).

Unfortunately that is also a bit of overhead, as the former `case myCase = "its_raw_value"` then gets distributed over

- the regular case (without the raw value String): `case myCase` (the definition)
- a switch in the `init?(rawValue:)` method: `... case "its_raw_value": return .myCase ...`
- a switch in the required `rawValue` property: `... case .myCase: return "its_raw_value" ...`

I think I have a nice way to reduce that a little and keep the raw values from floating around too much. I wrote a playground to illustrate and will simply paste it here:

---

```
// define protocol and a default implementation
protocol SloppyRawRepresentable
where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue: Hashable, Self: CaseIterable {
}
extension SloppyRawRepresentable {
    init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        var tempMapping = [RawValue: Self]()
        for oneCase in Self.allCases {
            // first come first served. any case after the first having the same
            // raw value is simply ignored, so the first is the "default"
            if tempMapping[oneCase.rawValue] == nil {
                tempMapping[oneCase.rawValue] = oneCase
            }
        }
        guard let candidate = tempMapping[rawValue] else { return nil }
        self = candidate
    }
}

// use it. Note we don't need the init
enum EventNames: SloppyRawRepresentable {
    typealias RawValue = String

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .standardEvent: return "standard"
        case .joesConfig: return "iAmJoe"
        case .myConfig: return "iAmJoe"
        }
    }

    case standardEvent
    case joesConfig
    case myConfig
}

// some example output

print(EventNames.standardEvent)
print(EventNames.joesConfig)
print(EventNames.myConfig)

print(EventNames.standardEvent.rawValue)
print(EventNames.joesConfig.rawValue)
print(EventNames.myConfig.rawValue)

print(EventNames(rawValue: "standard")!)
print(EventNames(rawValue: "iAmJoe")!)
print(EventNames(rawValue: "iAmJoe")!)

print(EventNames(rawValue: "standard")!.rawValue)
print(EventNames(rawValue: "iAmJoe")!.rawValue)
print(EventNames(rawValue: "iAmJoe")!.rawValue)
```

It should be self-explanatory. The case definition and assigning it its raw value is still split, I don't think there's a way around that, but it can come in handy. Of course all this requires the `RawValue` be constraint and I rely on the enum be `CaseIterable` to easily construct that helper dictionary, but I think that should be okay, performance wise.

Answer (score -1):

*Disclaimer: I'm not recommending this. Most people would not consider best practice. There are downsides, depending on the application. Let's just say these ideas are theoretical, hypothetical, impure, just presented for contemplation*

One possibility is to add some sort of meaningless differentiator sufficient to thwart Swift's check for identity that doesn't affect what you are doing with the raw values in your code.

He's an example with a `Float`, where, in music, A♯ (A sharp) is the same frequency as B♭ (B flat). They are both different annotations for the same thing, in other words.

Differences measured in microHz are meaningless to audio engines, yet sufficient to differentiate case values in a Swift enumeration.  In other words, practically speaking, there is no difference between 116.540 and 116.540001 in most music applications:

```
enum NoteFrequency : Float = {
   case A = 110.0, A_SHARP = 116.540, B_FLAT = 116.540001
}
```

Going from quasi-tolerable to uglier: For strings that only get assigned and printed you might add a non-printable character to differentiate.

Obviously this has downsides (potentially serious), if you do something like this and later you (or someone else) might be unaware of what you did, and writes code that doesn't account for it (such as using in rawValue of an enumeration in String comparisons) and their code fails. To make this work in String comparisons you'd have to probably do something to ignore the last character or lop it the unprintable character with `myEnumString.rawValue.dropLast()` before comparing...

```
 enum Animals : String = {
     case CAT = "Feline\u{01}", LION = "Feline\u{02}"
 }
```