# Swift enum custom raw type not expressible by different literals

Tags: swift, enums

I was reading through the wonderful [blog post by Jon Sundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/enums-with-custom-raw-types/) where he is trying to demonstrate how one can use custom raw values with Swift `Enum`s.

I had a play around with his code and made up a bit of a contrived example to see how robust the Enums with custom raw types are.

I wondered if I can make a type, instance of which can be used as a raw value whilst being expressible by both `String` and `Integer` literals. When I implemented `ExpressiblebyIntegerLiteral` the `String` part did not work the way I expected and I'm not quite sure why.

Here is the code (the question follows the code):

```
import Foundation

struct Path: Equatable {
    var string: String
    var int: Int
}

enum Target: Path {
    case content
    case resources
    case images = "resources/images"
}

extension Path: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    init(stringLiteral: String) {
        string = stringLiteral
        int = 0
    }

    init(integerLiteral: Int) {
        string = ""
        int = integerLiteral
    }
}

if let stringTarget = Target(rawValue: "content") {
   print("stringTarget: \(stringTarget)")
}

if let intTarget = Target(rawValue: 1) {
   print("intTarget: \(intTarget)")
}
```

What I expected the above code to produce is both `stringTarget` and `intTarget` being initialized to appropriate `Enum` cases, however, the `stringTarget` one turns out to be `nil`.

If you remove the conformance to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` protocol (and the appropriate block of code which initializes `intTarget`), the `stringTarget` automagically gets initialized as I expected: into `Target.string` case.

Could someone please explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: I discovered this technique: [non-unique raw values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62884952/13426627). But this looks cool, I'm going to give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solving your Question

> What I expected the above code to produce is both `stringTarget` and `intTarget` being initialized to appropriate `Enum` cases, however, the stringTarget one turns out to be `nil`.

They aren't nil. They are this: `""`

This happens because both the `.content` and `.resources` cases are not explicitly defined by a String. And because of this, they both take the `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` route, and are hence defined as this `""`

```swift
init(integerLiteral: Int) {
    string = "" // see
    int = integerLiteral
}
```

---

## Solved for Int

Use this fancy method in place of `IntValue(rawValue: 1)`:

```swift
func IntValue(_ this: Int) -> String? {
    return Target(rawValue: 0) != nil ? String(describing: Target(rawValue: 0)!) : nil
}
```

---

## Solved for String

First, conform your enum to `CaseIterable`, like so:

```swift
enum Target: Path, CaseIterable {
```

Next, use this fancy method in place of `Target(rawValue: "content")`:

```swift
func StringValue(_ this: String) -> String? {
    return Target.allCases.contains { this == String(describing: $0) } ? this : nil
}
```

---

## Truly solved for String

Now, I've removed a crucial bug where `case foo = "bar"` can be found both as 'foo' or 'bar'. If you don't want this, use this code instead:

```swift
func StringValue(_ this: String) -> String? {
    var found: String? = nil
    _ = Target.allCases.filter {
        if let a = Target(rawValue: Path.init(string: this, int: 0)) {
            found = String(describing: a)
            return this == String(describing: a)
        }
        found = String(describing: $0)
        return this == String(describing: $0)
    }
    return found
}
```

---

## Custom Raw Values for Enums

Here's a quick tutorial:

I am wondering if enum can conform it's rawValue to the ClosedRange struct, just like it can conform to String.

```swift
enum Foo: ClosedRange<Int> {
    case bar = 1...4
}
```

Obviously this is not an option, since `1...4` is not a literal

This seems to work:

```swift
enum Foo: ClosedRange<Int> {
    case foo = "1...3"
    case bar = "1...4"
    func overlaps(_ with: Foo) -> Bool { return self.rawValue.overlaps(with.rawValue) }
}
```

```swift
extension ClosedRange: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public typealias StringLiteralType = String
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        let v = value.split(separator: ".")

        switch Bound.self {
        case is Int.Type: self = (Int(v[0])! as! Bound)...(Int(v[1])! as! Bound)
        default: fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

It allows you to do this:

```
print(Foo.foo.overlaps(Foo.bar))
```

- You can add more types like `Double` or `String` using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46224492/13426627)

---

Side Note: My attempt allows for [non-unique rawValues (SR-13212)](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13212) which is a shame. But I'm not thinking that is fixable:

```swift
enum Foo: ClosedRange<Int> {
    case foo = "1...3"
    case bar = "1...4"
    case bar = "1...04" // Duplicate, but Swift allows it.
}
```

---